# Creating the Minecraft Nether Portal in Blender

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing

Perhaps a reference video would be needed to show this, but to clarify, merely the portal and its animations appear nearly impossible to create, the frame itself is simple diffusion and optional reflection. Mind this is using cycles.
[image]

I though the best way to attain this would be to have the position of the camera changing cause a movement of the portal textures however it has proven futile.

And so I ask, is this possible in Cycles?

EDIT:

My original plan was to use the UV Warp modifier to create the movement effect, with several planes underneath each other to create the depth. However, the way it appears to be a void, another area is the piece I lack.

The frame of the portal, again, is not a problem.

In reference to a comment that referenced a similar concept using a Nether portal that showed the Nether upon the other side, is similar, however there is no need to create another world on the other side, as I want to stay true to the visual mechanics of Minecraft.

Here is an example of the in-game version of what the goal is. 
https://youtu.be/ZpJiEbgo3Z4

Comment: You mean something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NF_KV7Z0JGQ ?

Comment: Create two scenes, make sure the camera movements in both scenes are the same, give the portal a holdout shader and overlap the scenes using an alpha over node.

Comment: The best way to get help is if you show an example of what you are after and detail what you've done that didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

In ***Cycles*** you may achieve this cool effect creating two different *Scenes* and combining them in ***compositor*** using the ***Alpha Over*** node (with a ***Holdout*** shader as a mask).
[image]

First check the Transparent checkbox in the *Film* panel of the *Render* header.
[image]

Create a *plane* and place it so it fits the door's jamb. Give it a ***Holdout*** shader. It will be used as a mask for mixing the two scenes in one render.
[image]

Create a new ***Scene*** (press the **+** button in the very top header), then choose *New*.
[image]

Now you have two scenes. You may switch between them as pictured below. Build two different worlds in each one. Your *Camera* and *door object* with *holdout plane* should be in the first Scene.
***NOTE:*** *Remember to change all the settings (such as render engine type, render settings etc.) for the nelwly created scene, so it fits the previous one.*
[image]

Now select the *Camera* and *door object*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>-->*Objects to Scene* and choose the second *Scene* (*Scene.001*). Objects origins should change their colors to blue- it means they're linked. Now you got them present in both scenes.
[image]

Now being in the first *Scene* go to the ***Node Editor*** (*compositing nodes*), add two *Render Layers* nodes, choose different scene for each one, render each scene (press the *camera icon*) and finally mix them using ***Alpha Over*** node (*Add*-->*Color*-->*Alpha Over*).
[image]

Open the *Uv Editor* in separate window and render (<kbd>F12</kbd>) being in the first *Scene* . Thanks to ***Alpha Over*** node your 'magic portal' is ready.
[image]
[image]

---

***BONUS:*** To 'pass through' the other side of the portal you have to animate the *Alpha Over* node's *Factor* value. Keyframe it (<kbd>I</kbd>) with value *1.000* at the start of your animation, then go to the point when your camera 'doesn't see', what's on the other side of the portal and keyframe it again. Now go to the next frame (where your camera is behind the *holdout plane*), change the Fac value to *0.000* and keyframe it. After rendering you'll be on the other side :).
[image]