# Fly through a window into a new world / scene?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, windows

I have a window in an empty space. I need to show another world through that window and also have the camera fly through the window into the new world. 
Any tips on how to achieve this effect?
[image: Window]

Comment: You could use the same camera object across different scenes for seamless movement, but then composite the results in post production, with alpha over the two scenes rendered frames

Comment: That sounds like a good idea I'll give it a go! Thanks

Comment: Be sure to mask both scenes, especially the window accordingly so you can correctly composite them together.

Comment: Similar question was asked some time ago I guess: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61965/creating-the-minecraft-end-portal-in-blender @Duarte Farrajota Ramos Maybe you should write an answer- it may be very helpful.

Comment: @PaulGonet I would, but compositing is not really my area, so not sure I could go into much detail or produce a quality answer. If you know more about it than I do, maybe you can grab the opportunity ;)