# Another world inside of a portal issues

Tags: cycles-render-engine

As the titles says I'm having issues creating a portal that has another world in it. I tried the following guide to the letter:
[Creating the Minecraft End Portal in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61965/creating-the-minecraft-end-portal-in-blender)
but it isn't working. I was hoping someone could take a look at my file and tell me where I am messing up and what I am missing. Preferably with images because I'm still new-ish to blender and don't know all the names or locations of every function but any help is completely and utter welcome! I am destroying my brain over this! LOL!

My goal is to have the crystals be only seen inside the portal/gold object in the sense. Thank you so much in advanced!

Here is the file:
https://mega.nz/#!T2xhwKrQ!ZHjC0fWvLK3gdJn3WQ8kWJquqJFmNGVTepUfXwxK6eI

Comment: The correct way to achieve this is through render layers and compositing.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying back! But may I ask for a little more detail? Sorry, as I said I'm a bit new-ish to blender and have only once, and with very mixed results, used render layers! Lol! How would you go about achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is a tutorial on how to create a portal using scenes, render layers, object id and compositing. Please try to achieve it while reading the tutorial.

First you want to have the first world and the portal.

[image]

Note that i set the plane pass index to 1, this is crucial.

Then you need the second world, I did a terrain with a sunlamp.
Create them in the second scene and link your camera here afterward (`ctrl+L->link to scene`).

[image]

After this you need to set up the render layers, for use with compositing.
Go to render layer panel, unfold the pass menu and select `object index`

[image]

For the scene 2, you don't need to set the object index because the plane you will be using for splicing the two world is only present in the first scene.

Everything is setup, open the node editor and select the compositing nodes.

Here you start with a render layer that is set on render layer one, scene one (we are just using one scene in our case) and a composite output.

Just add another render layer, set in on scene 2, add an `alpha over` node and connect your two layers color output on that node, the factor is the plane, so connect the indexOB that we activated earlier for the first layer to an `IDMask` node then to the factor of the `alpha over`. Easier to just look at the picture here:

[image]

Now you can just render.

[image]

Being an after effect, there is no such thing as compatibility issues regarding wether you are using cycles, eevie, or blender internal.

Comment: You, my friend, are a GOD! Thank you so much! This did the trick! I really appreciate you taking the time out of your day to help me!

Comment: You'r welcome. Fact is I had tried this a long time ago without succes but this time it worked. So thank you for asking and having been patien

Comment: Hi @Yvain thanks for this solution, its great. I have one question - you mention that since it is an after effect it doesn't matter whether you are using cycles, eevee etc. However, I am using 2.8 and it is not possible to do this step `"After this you need to set up the render layers, for use with compositing. Go to render layer panel, unfold the pass menu and select object index"` when in eevee - as `object index` does not exist as a check in the layer panel. Is there an alternative way? I would love to be able t do this in eevee. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was working in 2.7 and did not notice that eevee has no support for render layers. I don't know how you could do this, this might be impossible, you might find a way... but I would advise that you use cycles and stick to this. There are many way to optimize your render so that it's not too long, especially look upon the `filter glossy` setting and don't use an unnecessary high amount of light bounces. Your render will just be great and more realistic that with eevee.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. I don't mind doing it in cycles, its just, as you mention, it takes a lot longer. I just looked at the `filter glossy` setting which is currently at 1 - should it go up or down to speed it up?  Also light bounces are set by default at 12 - what would be a reasonable setting? Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: @Nick the glossy filter will not make the render faster, it gets rid of the glossy details, so that the image looks smoother with less samples. You can quickly have a feel of what it does by using the `progressive refine` render option. With the glossy filter set to about `0.5` you are good to heavily lower the sampling, even more when set to 1 or max (5). As for the light rays it depends on the scene you are rendering, honestly all I know is that it's the number or rays that are calculated for each pixels at each sample. Unless the scene is really dark it would not make much difference.

Comment: Thanks @Yvain much appreciated.