# realtime window into a scene

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, masking, id-mask

I have a realtime view into a room as a mask on a plane. All you can see of the room is through the mask /2D plane that is exported as a 3D model (.GLtf or .glb preferably)

I achieve this effect in Unity with masks, but I cant figure it out Blender...
here is a video:
https://youtu.be/jIz55M0uoqI

I am not rendering but exporting as a model that you rotate around like a 2D/3D playing card.

There is so much work being done now with masks in Blender I was hoping that something would be possible...

The other way to think about this might be to have a mirror that was reflecting a room in realtime but you would be hiding the room.

Any ideas?

Thanks
~be

Comment: So would this be like a portal mentioned here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147113/another-world-inside-of-a-portal-issues

Comment: @Yohello1 Yes, like this! Do you think it will work as n exported model?
Thanks! I will try to recreate it in Blender 2.8

Comment: I don't think it will work in an exported model sadly because of how it works.

Comment: Thanks @Yohello I bet this will come soon