# Making a portal effect in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-layers

**Case**

I followed this [outdated tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ol0__bZHcU4&t=8s&ab_channel=mistermaster7492) to create an effect that I want (being able to see a completely different world through an object (a shield in this case). I got this to work in blender 2.8+.

The problem is that I have to render in cycles due to some nodes being used and these are only available in cycles. At the moment blender renders all 3 layers and smacks them together to generate the desired result which takes 3x as long. so my question is:

1. How can I preview this effect without having to render it?
2. How can I tell blender to only render 1 layer to preview other effects?

Here are some screenshot of my project, hope it helps.

[image: Nodes I am using]

Shiled being used as mask
[image: Shiled being used ask mask]

other dimension I want to capture by watching through the shield
[image: other dimension I want to capture by watching through the shield]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137679/portal-effect-in-eevee

Comment: you can use the search box at the top for commonly asked questions https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61965/creating-the-minecraft-end-portal-in-blender